# L'expression « partir au bord de la mer »

Tags: expressions, usage, géographie

Est-ce que c'est vrai, que en français (dans la langue courante) on dit « partir au bord de la mer » quand on part pour aller simplement « à la mer » ?

On peut dire plus simplement « partir à la mer » ou « aller à la mer » ?

---

How to say correctly in French « I'm going to the sea » ?
Are there different correct ways to say it in the common spoken language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Est-ce que c'est vrai, que en français (dans la langue courante) on dit « partir au bord de la mer » quand on part pour aller simplement « à la mer » ?

Oui, c'est l'une des façons de le dire.

> On peut dire plus simplement « partir à la mer » ou « aller à la mer » ?

Oui, on peut aussi. « Aller à la mer » est très courant, en particulier lorsqu'on l'oppose à « Aller à la montagne/à la campagne ».

Si l'on va « sur ou dans la mer », on dira plutôt « Je vais faire du bateau, de la plongée; etc. ».

---

> How to say correctly in French « I'm going to the sea » ? Are there different correct ways to say it in the common spoken language?

There are many ways to say it:

- Aller à la mer (often vs "aller à la montagne").
- Aller au bord de la mer.
- Aller sur la côte.
- Aller à la plage.

If the plan is to go further toward the sea, one can be more descriptive:

- Aller en mer
- Aller faire du bateau/de la voile/de la plongée/du surf/...

Answer (score 2):

Depends on whether you mean *go to sea*, as in a boat, or *go to the seashore* or *go to the seaside*.

In other words, it's the same difference as in English.

In English, *go to the sea* (“*aller à la mer*”) is sometimes used to mean *go to the seashore* (“*aller sur les côtes*  / *les bords de mer*”). *Go to sea* (“aller en mer”) is not ambiguous in the same way as *go to the sea*.

Comment: Can you please write me the different versions? Thank you.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. *partir a la mer* means *go to sea*, as far as I know. *partir au bord de la mer* means *go to the seaside*. Do you mean go out to sea in a boat or go to the seashore for a swim, tan, vollyball, and picnic?

Comment: For example, you planned to go to Nice for the weekend. How would you answer to your friend asking: "Where are you going?" "Je vais à Nice" ou "Je pars à la mer" ou "Je pars au bord de la mer"...?

Comment: If I were going to Nice, for whatever reason: "*à Nice.*" Otherwise: "*au bord de la mer.*"

Comment: @AndreaCarrer: I added the French equivalents.